# Fastest way to get all the points between two (X,Y) coordinates in python

Tags: python, numpy, gis, vectorization, interpolation

So I have a `shapely` `LineString`:

```
print np.round(shapely_intersecting_lines.coords).astype(np.int) 
>>> array([[ 1520, -1140],
           [ 1412,  -973]])
```

This can be interpreted as a `numpy` array as well as seen above.

I want to get all the points in between, that is I want to get the points of the line in between as integer values. The output should be something like this:

```
array([[ 1520, -1140],
       [ 1519, -1139],
       [ 1519, -1138],
       ..., 
       [ 1413,  -975],
       [ 1412,  -974],
       [ 1412,  -973]], dtype=int32)
```

I posted this earlier in [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263859/fast-way-to-get-all-points-as-integer-of-a-linestring-in-shapely) hoping there was a solution in `shapely` that was efficient. The solution was good at first, however, the solution is now too slow as I run this over 50000 times in my code. On my computer each loop takes about 0.03s resulting in over a day of running. It is too slow for what I need here and was hoping to see if anyone knows of a vectorized solution to this.

Comment: You need [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bresenham may be smart but I'm pretty sure brute force vectorization is faster. I've written two variants - the first is easier to read, the second is faster (80 us vs 50 us).

**Update** Fixed a  bug (thanks @Varlor) and added an nd variant.

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def connect(ends):
    d0, d1 = np.abs(np.diff(ends, axis=0))[0]
    if d0 > d1: 
        return np.c_[np.linspace(ends[0, 0], ends[1, 0], d0+1, dtype=np.int32),
                     np.round(np.linspace(ends[0, 1], ends[1, 1], d0+1))
                     .astype(np.int32)]
    else:
        return np.c_[np.round(np.linspace(ends[0, 0], ends[1, 0], d1+1))
                     .astype(np.int32),
                     np.linspace(ends[0, 1], ends[1, 1], d1+1, dtype=np.int32)]


def connect2(ends):
    d0, d1 = np.diff(ends, axis=0)[0]
    if np.abs(d0) > np.abs(d1): 
        return np.c_[np.arange(ends[0, 0], ends[1,0] + np.sign(d0), np.sign(d0), dtype=np.int32),
                     np.arange(ends[0, 1] * np.abs(d0) + np.abs(d0)//2,
                               ends[0, 1] * np.abs(d0) + np.abs(d0)//2 + (np.abs(d0)+1) * d1, d1, dtype=np.int32) // np.abs(d0)]
    else:
        return np.c_[np.arange(ends[0, 0] * np.abs(d1) + np.abs(d1)//2,
                               ends[0, 0] * np.abs(d1) + np.abs(d1)//2 + (np.abs(d1)+1) * d0, d0, dtype=np.int32) // np.abs(d1),
                     np.arange(ends[0, 1], ends[1,1] + np.sign(d1), np.sign(d1), dtype=np.int32)]


def connect_nd(ends):
    d = np.diff(ends, axis=0)[0]
    j = np.argmax(np.abs(d))
    D = d[j]
    aD = np.abs(D)
    return ends[0] + (np.outer(np.arange(aD + 1), d) + (aD//2)) // aD


ends = np.array([[ 1520, -1140],
                 [ 1412,  -73]])

ends_4d = np.array([[  100, -302, 101, -49],
                    [ -100,  -45, 112, 100]])

print(connect(ends))
print(connect_nd(ends_4d))


assert np.all(connect(ends)==connect2(ends))
assert np.all(connect(ends)==connect_nd(ends))
assert np.all(connect(ends)==connect(ends[:, ::-1])[:, ::-1])
assert np.all(connect(ends)==connect(ends[::-1])[::-1])

print(timeit('f(ends)', globals={'f': connect, 'ends': ends}, number=10000)*100, 'us')
print(timeit('f(ends)', globals={'f': connect2, 'ends': ends}, number=10000)*100, 'us')
print(timeit('f(ends)', globals={'f': connect_nd, 'ends': ends}, number=10000)*100, 'us')
```

Sample output:

```
[[ 1520 -1140]
 [ 1520 -1139]
 [ 1520 -1138]
 ..., 
 [ 1412   -75]
 [ 1412   -74]
 [ 1412   -73]]
[[ 100 -302  101  -49]
 [  99 -301  101  -48]
 [  98 -300  101  -48]
 ..., 
 [ -98  -47  112   99]
 [ -99  -46  112   99]
 [-100  -45  112  100]]
78.8237597000034 us
48.02509490000375 us
62.78072760001123 us
```

Comment: Is that also possible to do that in 3D ?

Comment: @Varlor ok, my first take was correct after all: find the axis with the greatest difference. Use this difference + 1 as your number of points and create the coordinates in exactly the same way as in 2D. The two non-longest axes are treated the same in 3D.

Comment: Hmm, so i have to do d0,d1 = np.diff(ends,axis=0)[0]+1 ? So the first np.arange generates all points of x-axis, and the second np.arange all points of the y-axis?, what does the else case is for? could you give an example how the case for z-axis would look like? Best regards! :)

Comment: and i have to check many cases arent I? d0>d1, d0>d2 and so on?

Comment: @Varlor The simplest you could do: `d = np.max(np.abs(np.diff(ends, axis=0)))` `np.array([np.linspace(*e.T, d+1, dtype=np.int32) for e in ends.T + 0.5], order='F').T`.

Comment: this function for the whole calculation?

Comment: Because for ends = np.array([[ 1520, -1140, 1],[ 1412,  -973, 1]]) it generates the points [ 1520, -1139, 1] and [ 1412  -972     1] at the start and beginning

Comment: @Varlor Oops! So `int` is rounding towards zero, I'll have to fix the post. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Ok so instead of int, i have to take float32? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164889/discussion-between-varlor-and-paul-panzer).

Comment: Is it possible to do this also for smaller grid, lets say 0.5 in x,y,z direction?

Comment: @Varlor Just divide `ends` by `0.5`, do the integer calculation and multiply the result with `0.5`.

Comment: But then i get the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'numpy.float64' and 'int' in the return line

Comment: @Varlor For the sake of exercise you could try solving those small things by yourself, y'know. Ok, try // 2 instead of >> 1.

Comment: connect2() crashed for me. Seems it doesn't like when one of the coordinates is identical between 2 points. connect() worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's Bresenhams line algorithm as a generator.  If you want a list just call list() on the output:

```
def line(x0, y0, x1, y1):
    deltax = x1-x0
    dxsign = int(abs(deltax)/deltax)
    deltay = y1-y0
    dysign = int(abs(deltay)/deltay)
    deltaerr = abs(deltay/deltax)
    error = 0
    y = y0
    for x in range(x0, x1, dxsign):
        yield x, y
        error = error + deltaerr
        while error >= 0.5:
            y += dysign
            error -= 1
    yield x1, y1
```

Comment: This doesn't compute the points for a "steep" line correctly.  For example, `line(0, 0, 2, 5)` generates `(0, 0), (1, 3), (2, 5)`, which skips two grid lines as it moves up from (0,0) to (2, 5).

Comment: Ah right, this only works for the first octant.  Octant convertsions can be found on the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Good base code to start:

```py
def points_between(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    
    d0 = x2 - x1
    d1 = y2 - y1
    
    count = max(abs(d1+1), abs(d0+1))

    if d0 == 0:
        return (
            np.full(count, x1),
            np.round(np.linspace(y1, y2, count)).astype(np.int32)
        )

    if d1 == 0:
        return (
            np.round(np.linspace(x1, x2, count)).astype(np.int32),
            np.full(count, y1),  
        )

    return (
        np.round(np.linspace(x1, x2, count)).astype(np.int32),
        np.round(np.linspace(y1, y2, count)).astype(np.int32)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a short  solution using np library

```py
    import numpy as np
    x = [1,2,3]
    y = [5,6,7]
    ks,cs = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    np.vstack((ks.flatten(),cs.flatten())).T
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using generators so that way you will save memory

```
import numpy as np
import math

d = np.array(
    [
        [1520,-1140],
        [1412,-973]
    ],dtype=float);
rise = d[0,1]-d[1,1];
run = d[0,0]-d[1,0];
slope = rise/run;
print slope

fromPt = d[0];
sign = 1
if (slope<0):
    sign = -1;
points = ([d[0,0]+sign*i,math.floor(d[0,1]+(sign*i*slope))] for i in xrange(1+int(math.ceil(abs(d[0,0]-d[1,0])))))
for pt in points:
    print pt
```