# Python: Get all coordinates between two 3D points or draw a 3D Line

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vtk, scikit-image

I have the following problem. I have 3D point coordinates and I want to conenct them in an array or "draw a line" like you can do it in 2D with skimage(http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.line). **The optimal case would be if i could directly draw a cylinder with a radius in an array and give different radius different values like rings arround the line.(wrinkles could be a problem here)**. There have been approaches to do that but they are not the right thing i think like here:

["Draw" a 3d line into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276466/draw-a-3d-line-into-an-array)

With the two approaches of @Paul Panzer ([Fastest way to get all the points between two (X,Y) coordinates in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704008/fastest-way-to-get-all-the-points-between-two-x-y-coordinates-in-python)) you get all coordinates between two 2D Points, but how would it look like in 3D, esspecially the second approach which is faster?:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def connect(ends):
    d0, d1 = np.abs(np.diff(ends, axis=0))[0]
    if d0 > d1: 
        return np.c_[np.linspace(ends[0, 0], ends[1, 0], d0+1, dtype=np.int32),
                     np.linspace(ends[0, 1]+0.5, ends[1, 1]+0.5, d0+1, dtype=np.int32)]
    else:
        return np.c_[np.linspace(ends[0, 0]+0.5, ends[1, 0]+0.5, d1+1, dtype=np.int32),
                     np.linspace(ends[0, 1], ends[1, 1], d1+1, dtype=np.int32)]


def connect2(ends):
    d0, d1 = np.diff(ends, axis=0)[0]
    if np.abs(d0) > np.abs(d1): 
        return np.c_[np.arange(ends[0, 0], ends[1,0] + np.sign(d0), np.sign(d0), dtype=np.int32),
                     np.arange(ends[0, 1] * np.abs(d0) + np.abs(d0)//2,
                               ends[0, 1] * np.abs(d0) + np.abs(d0)//2 + (np.abs(d0)+1) * d1, d1, dtype=np.int32) // np.abs(d0)]
    else:
        return np.c_[np.arange(ends[0, 0] * np.abs(d1) + np.abs(d1)//2,
                               ends[0, 0] * np.abs(d1) + np.abs(d1)//2 + (np.abs(d1)+1) * d0, d0, dtype=np.int32) // np.abs(d1),
                     np.arange(ends[0, 1], ends[1,1] + np.sign(d1), np.sign(d1), dtype=np.int32)]


ends = np.array([[ 1520, -1140],
                 [ 1412,  -973]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question 'vtk', I assume you can use it in your code. In that case, I think [vtkTubeFilter](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkTubeFilter.html#details) does exactly what you are looking for - you create a `vtkPolyData` with all your line segments (you have your endpoints for that) and for each segment, the filter generates a cylinder. You can also specify different radius for each segment as you wanted: call `SetVaryRadiusToVaryRadiusByScalar()` on the filter to turn it on and provide the array with radii as scalar data.

You can find a code example that does all that (and more) here: https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/VisualizationAlgorithms/TubesWithVaryingRadiusAndColors

Comment: I used the TubeFilter before, but I think the problem here is that theTubeFilter only is the contour of the cylinder. To get all coordinates in the inner of the Tube I have to use vtk.vtkSelectEnclosedPoints() which is very time consuming.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the problem I think, you are working with discrete volumetric data and you want to fill all voxels along the line(s)...in that case, I can't help :(